# Como colocar logo reponsivo no meu site

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Olá,

Estou tendo um problema com a logo do meu blog que depois de sua atualização somente ela não esta ficando responsiva.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber o que devo alterar no css. Só consegui encontrar "logo" nos seguintes codigos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Coloca o código no lugar da imagem.

Comment: Ta confuso analisar o código pelas imagens, mas adiantando..as imagens possuem a classe `img-responsive`? Pois essa é a classe do bootstrap para tornar imagens responsivas.

Comment: Tenta colocando o width da sua logo em 100%. Ou faz uma logo diferente e usa media query pra mostrar essa outra no mobile.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: É recomendável  que você utilize as ferramentas destinadas a postagem de código, em vez de print. Pois isso auxilia as pessoas que vão testar e ajustar o teu código.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a classe "img-responsive" do boostrap([Documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp)) no elemento da imagem do seu banner.

Ex:

```
<img src="teste.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
```

Mas é importante lembrar que isso vai diminuir a imagem proporcionalmente ao espaço destinado a ela. No seu caso, provavelmente ficará ilegível. Uma solução melhor requer que você crie uma imagem alternativa para resoluções menores, ou "quebre" esse banner em pequenas imagens para que possam aparecer uma embaixo da outra.